# downloading a file with Watin

Tags: firefox, download, watin

How can i download a file with watin? I searched a lot and tryied but i cant get it.
I only want to click on a link that have a download and save it. I used examples that i found but without success. The problem is that i use "WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(15)" but the 15 seconds pass and throw and exception: WatiN.Core.Exceptions.WatiNException : Has not shown dialog after 15 seconds.

This is the code:

```
FileDownloadHandler download = new FileDownloadHandler("C:/Development/Test/Downloads/" + "excel" + ".xls");
            using (new UseDialogOnce(browser.DialogWatcher, download))
            {
                browser.Button(Find.ById("id_of_the_button")).ClickNoWait();
                download.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(15);
                download.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(150);                
                browser.RemoveDialogHandler(download);
            }
```

Please, help!

Comment: i forgot to say, but im using firefox to handle that (nevermind, i also tryed IE

Answer (score 2):

I did discover one issue that plagued me

```
FileDownloadHandler handler = new FileDownloadHandler(@"c:\temp\file.csv");
browser.DialogWatcher.CloseUnhandledDialogs = false;
using (new UseDialogOnce(browser.DialogWatcher, handler))
{
    browser.Link(Find.ByText("July2011")).Click();
    handler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(15);
    handler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(240);
}
```

Note the inclusion of the "CloseUnhandledDialogs = false" line.  My save dialog popup was disappearing immediately and it took me forever to realize what was going on.

Comment: I freaking love you! I've been struggling with the disappearing save dialog for a while and was completely bewildered! I thought it was an issue with IE and not anything to do with code.

Answer (score 0):

I had used the following code snippet that worked absolutely fine

```
FileDownloadHandler download = new FileDownloadHandler("C:\\Development\\Test\\Downloads\\" + "excel" + ".xls");
browser.AddDialogHandler(download);
browser.Button(Find.ById("id_of_the_button")).ClickNoWait();
download.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(15);
download.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(150);                
browser.RemoveDialogHandler(download);
```

The only difference in the code snippet that I used was that I used a backslash with the escape character and that I added and removed the DialogHandler without an using block.

~Ashish Narmen

Answer (score 0):

To Download Documents using WATIN

```
 public FileDownloadHandler fileDownloadHandler;

 /*CLICK ON THE FILE LINK TO DOWNLOAD..IT WILL PROMPT FOR FILE DOWNLOAD DIALOG..TO HANDLE THAT DIALOG USE THE BELOW CODE*/

  fileDownloadHandler = new FileDownloadHandler(//THE PATH IN WHICH YOU DOWNLOAD DOCUMENTS//);
    try
    {
        using (new UseDialogOnce(ie.DialogWatcher, fileDownloadHandler))
        {                                               
          download();
        }            
    }
    catch (WatiN.Core.Exceptions.WatiNException ex)
    {
      download();
    }
    public void download()
    {
         try
        {
            fileDownloadHandler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(8);
        }
        catch (WatiN.Core.Exceptions.WatiNException ex)
        {
            download();
        }
    }
```